# Handling the Arduino Map() equation in Java with very large ranges

Tags: java, data-structures, equation

I've been trying to come up with an equation to turn 3 sets of numbers into r,g,b values respectively and I decided that the most effective way to do that was to use this

`long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max) { return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min; }`

equation that's embedded in the map() function that arduino, processing and JavaScript use sometimes. However, I realized while using it though that my range of numbers are skewed too wildly given that my max is so much higher than the next biggest number before it (for the blue parameter the max is 2,169,000 and the next max under it is 1,400,000, and then everything else is in the hundred thousands down to the hundreds) so my mapping makes all the smaller numbers in the set turn into extremely small decimals which can't show up as anything other than black in the rgb scale.

I was wondering how I can make up for this issue and be able to map every number reliably in a range from (0,255).

This is the current code that I'm attempting. I tried to calculate the mins, maxes and averages for each 3 parameters (red, blue and other) and these are the results formatted as red:blue:other
and other is going to represent green.

Minimums: 53:5:0
Maximums: 885333:2216903:78831
Averages: 19324:20816:746

The ranges in those numbers are way too huge to make my colors show up correctly.

(Cv is a Map that contains the name of the area which I'm taking 3 numbers from and a separate class that contains fields red, blue, and other for that area).

```
int maxRed = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxBlue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxOther = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minRed = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minBlue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minOther = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

   for(String hh : cv.keySet()){
    int r = cv.get(hh).red;    
    int b = cv.get(hh).blue;
    int o = cv.get(hh).other;
    averageR = averageR + r;
    averageO = averageO + o;
    averageB = averageB + b;
    
    //System.out.println(cv.get(hh).red + " " + cv.get(hh).blue + " " + cv.get(hh).other);
    if(r >= maxRed){maxRed = r;} 
    if(b >= maxBlue){maxBlue = b;}
    if(o >= maxOther){maxOther = o;}
    if(r <= minRed){minRed = r;} 
    if(b <= minBlue){minBlue = b;}
    if(o <= minOther){minOther = o;}
    //System.out.println(minRed + ":" + minBlue + ":" + minOther);
    
    }


///in a separate loop///
int r1 = cv.get(na).red;    
     int b1 = cv.get(na).blue;
     int o1 = cv.get(na).other;   
     double r = map(r1,minRed,maxRed,0,255);
     double g = map(o1,minOther,maxOther,0,255);
     double b = map(b1,minBlue,maxBlue,0,255);
```

When r,g and b are calculated, the result is that the highest numbers hitting around 700k+ are getting what I desire around 200-250 but anything below that shoots down to 30s and then super small decimals.

Comment: Maybe put the numbers on an exponential scale. Something like `(sqrt(vals[n]) \ sqrt(max(vals))) * 255`. You can also play around with things like log or ln instead of sqrt for different scaling.

Comment: @luckydog32 so to clarify, would that be a way to sort of “normalize” my equation or set of numbers and bring up the colors and values while keeping the same ratio?

Comment: it would change the linear ratio between numbers, especially high end while keeping the low end ratios less affected. I'm not sure what the values represent, but putting them on a exponential scale helps bring them down into a closer range.